# Invoking Test Methods with a Method for a unittest.TestCase Subclass Python

Tags: python, testing, python-unittest

I've been reading [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.main) for the `unittest` module, but I haven't been able to decipher if it's even possible to do what I'm looking to do. Specifically, I'd like to be able to do something like the following class:

```
class TestMyCode(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_code(self):
        self.assertTrue(True)

    # Not sure how to do implement this method below
    def run_tests(self):
        # This would run all of the tests in my class
        self.run()
```

The reason I would like to do this is because I would like to run my tests from within another Python file. E.g., say I'm writing code in another file:

```
from test_my_code import TestMyCode
tests = TestMyCode()
# Runs all of the tests from the TestMyCode subclass
tests.run_tests()
```

Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative to what you are trying to do would be to run the `main` module shown below. Make sure that the `test` module is available for import if you wish to run the tests in it. Hope this helps you!

---

**Module:** `test`

```
import unittest


class TestMyCode(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_code(self):
        self.assertTrue(True)
```

---

**Module:** `main`

```
import test


def run_tests(module):
    module.unittest.main(module.__name__)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    run_tests(test)
```

---

**Addendum:** To do what you are requesting, add a method that replicates some of the internal work done by `unittest.main` to run the tests. The following two modules help to demonstrate how you might go about modifying your `TestMyCode` class so that it can run tests on itself without outside help.

---

**Module:** `test_module`

```
import unittest


class TestMyCode(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_code(self):
        self.assertTrue(True)

    @classmethod
    def run_tests(cls):
        test = unittest.defaultTestLoader.loadTestsFromTestCase(cls)
        unittest.TextTestRunner().run(test)
```

---

**Module:** `main`

```
import test_module


def main():
    test_module.TestMyCode.run_tests()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: I think that I follow what you're saying, but with that solution wouldn't I have to run `main.py` from the command line? I'd like to be able to run all of the tests from a `unittest.TestCase` subclass with a single method call within a script. 

My thinking behind this is that I could then have a script take a set of commands and then only run certain tests if a command line arg, say `--test` is called.

Comment: @gr1zzlybe4r Two more modules have been added demonstrating what appears to be a solution to your question. The `TestMyCode` class has been modified so that tests can be run directly via a method of the class.

Comment: Thank you! This is what I was looking for. Marked the answer as correct.